# Jupyterlab terminal does not work, but cmd in windows works fine

Tags: powershell, cmd, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

#### Problem

- When I execute the .py extension file on jupyterlab terminal, another cmd screen shows up.
- To make it worse, if the .py file does not require inputs, the cmd screen disappears right away.
- Example is provided below.

#### What I would like to do

- Executing the .py file and seeing the results on the jupyterlab terminal!

#### Details

- I have made a simple scripts as below, and its file name is `why_cmd.py`

  ```
  for i in range(1,6):
      print(i)
  ```
- It works perfectly fine when I used cmd to run this `why_cmd.py`, as shown in the picture below.

[image]

- However, when I run this file on the jupyterlab terminal, it shows 2 weird behaviors

  1. I need to run files with the command `.\why_cmd.py` instead of `why_cmd.py`
  2. The code is executed on another cmd screen. And I cannot even see the results on the cmd screen because it turns off immediately.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a problem using Jupyterlab's terminal because it was powershell, not bash (window's cmd). So I followed the advice of @dhirschfeld
, as written in the [Jupyterlab's github issue page](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/9193). The instructions below will let you use the `bash` instead of `supershell` on the jupyterlab.

1. Go to advanced system settings
2. Open 'Environment Variables', and you can see the screenshot below. [image]
3. Add the codes below to the `User variables for (Account name)`, which is the section
   under the red number 1

```
Variable Name : SHELL 
Variable Value : cmd.exe
```